# why componentDidUpdate run multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-lifecycle

I really don't understand the react life cycle. I run console.log in componentDidUpdate() and saw that it ran multiple times
[Console showed that componentDidUpdate ran 3 times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slAdM.png)

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or it will be very difficult to help you.

Comment: The reason for a component to call componentDidUpdate() is this its state or props has been updated. This is caused by calling setState() in your component or the parent's component changing its props to your component.

Comment: ...or parent is re-rendered and this concrete child is not `PureComponent` so it's re-rendered too

Answer (score 8):

Maybe I can give you an extra example when your issue happens since I cannot see your code.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        const { something } = this.props;
        if (prevProps.something !== something) this.apiCall();
        console.log('something')
}
```

when you change your state or props, `componentDidUpdate` is being invoked, and apiCall function makes http request via `fetch` or `axios`, and change the state twice using `setState` function.

whenever `state` gets changed, new `render()` is being invoked and `componentDidUpdate` follows.

but the condition

```
if (prevProps.something !== something) this.apiCall();
```

may not be satisfied anymore, just console logging at this time instead of calling `apiCall` function which would trigger inifinite loop.

hope it helps.

Comment: I don't understand why `if (prevProps.something !== something) this.apiCall();` may not be satisfied anymore and console logging would trigger infinite loop.

Answer (score 5):

`componentDidUpdate()` is invoked immediately after updating occurs.

your problem may be accorded because the state has been changed, props received or parent re-rendred.

if you are new with React, I recommend you to read the following article:
[Post-Render with componentDidUpdate()](https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/postrender_with_componentdidupdate.html)